# Redirect from '/user/login' to '/user/me' in express with JWT and auth middleware

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, backend

I'm trying to redirect a user to their profile after logging them in. What I'm trying to do is when they log in, we will find the user by credentials and then generate and auth token from them (note I created a user const for testing purposes). After both are done, I'll set a header Authorization, use the token, and pass it to the /user/me route. Here are my routes:

**(login POST route, "/user/login"):**

```
router.post('/user/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(req.body.email, req.body.password)
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        
        res.header('Authorization', 'Bearer '+token)
        res.status(302).redirect('/user/me')
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send(err)
    }
})
```

**(profile route: "/user/me"):**

```
router.get('/user/me', auth, async (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user)
})
```

**(the "auth" middleware that I'm passing in the previous method):**

```
const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, SECRET_TOKEN)
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token})
        console.log(token)

        if(!user) {
            throw new Error("User not found")
        }

        req.token = token
        req.user = user
        next()

    } catch(err) {
        res.status(503).send({error: 'Please authenticate'})
    }
}
```

But whenever I try this, it gives my **503 error from the auth method**:

```
{
   "error": "Please authenticate"
}
```

The Authorization header passes correctly as I've seen in my dev tools.

For more information, here's what the **generateAuthToken** & **findByCredentials** methods look like:

```
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function() {
    const user = this

    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id.toString() }, SECRET_TOKEN)

    user.tokens = user.tokens.concat({token})

    await user.save()

    return token
}

userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({email})
    if(!user) {
        throw new Error({message: "Unable to log in."})
    }

    const isValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

    if(!isValid) {
        throw new Error({message: "Unable to log in."})
    }

    return user
}
```

For more more information, here's what my **User model** looks like:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        validate(value) {
            if(!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                throw new Error("Not a valid email")
            }
        } 
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate(value) {
            if(value === "password") {
                throw new Error("Enter a strong password.")
            }

            if(value.length < 8) {
                throw new Error("Enter minimum 8 letters for a password.")
            }
        } 
    },
    tokens: [{
        token:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }]
})
```

Comment: *"But whenever I try this, it gives my 503 error from the auth method:"* - You're sending 503 unconditionally. There are other things that can fail in your code, and all will lead to a 503. What do you see when you output the error itself?

Comment: @Tomalak My mistake, it says "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined".  Which would mean that the 'Authorization' header is undefined. How can I pass it from /user/login to /user/me?

Comment: @Tomalak I solved it using cookies. It works fine now. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by using cookies. It maybe a temporary work-around but I'll find resources to make it more secure!

**In the login route:**

```
res.cookie('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`, {
        maxAge: 60000,
})
```

**In the auth middleware**:

```
const token = req.cookies['Authorization'].replace('Bearer ', '')
```

Comment: You're supposed to set the Authorization header with every request. Using a cookie only side-steps the issue, because the browser manages cookie headers for you. Using cookies is not the best solution to this issue. Investigate the question of how to set the Authorization header consistently at the client side.

Comment: Well, that and rewrite your server code so it sends proper response codes, depending on the situation. 503 does not mean "please authenticate", it means "service unavailable" (i.e. "server down" and such). "unauthorized" is 401. And programming mistakes like *"Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"* are supposed to lead to 500.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions @Tomalak. I'm currently looking into everything you've suggested.